# Can't make greek sign of question ";" shown right

Tags: font-encodings, input-encodings, greek

I tried to make a greek text in Latex. But there is a small problem the sign of question ";" shows as upper dot.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\sloppy

\begin{document}

--- Καλά αν είναι έτσι! Αλλά θα λειτουργεί;
Τι θα κάνουμε, απλά θα καθίσουμε απ’ έξω,
θα βγάλουμε φωτογραφίες και αυτό ήτανε;
Δεν θα ανάψουμε ούτε ένα κεράκι;

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

I tried `\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}` and got more problem with encoding. After I tried  `\usepackage{ucs}` but result was the same.
Could somebody help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `?` for the question mark. The reasons for having `;` print the Greek semicolon (upper dot) are historical and due to how Greek had to be input, before UTF-8, via a transliteration map: the punctuation marks are Latin and the printed ones are their Greek counterparts.

Comment: filokalos, see also @egreg's answer, he posted an alternative solution (in case you haven't seen it).

Comment: You may also use xelatex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The “official” answer is “Use `?` for the question mark”.

The reasons for having `;` print the Greek semicolon (upper dot) are historical and due to how Greek had to be input, before UTF-8, via a transliteration map: the punctuation marks are Latin and the printed ones are their Greek counterparts.

If you have a recent and up-to-date TeX distribution (with `babel` version 3.9), you can define `;` as a shorthand for the question mark:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}[2013/10/10]

\useshorthands{;}
\defineshorthand{;}{?}

\begin{document}

--- Καλά αν είναι έτσι! Αλλά θα λειτουργεί;
Τι θα κάνουμε, απλά θα καθίσουμε απ’ έξω,
θα βγάλουμε φωτογραφίες και αυτό ήτανε;
Δεν θα ανάψουμε ούτε ένα κεράκι;

\end{document}
```

Note that `utf8` is preferable to `utf8x` with the newer TeX distributions.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you take a look at this [document about the Greek option for the `babel` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/greek/usage.pdf), this is a "feature", i.e. it's not a bug. There is a table that illustrates what you need to type in order to have a certain output (see page 2 of the document):

[image]