# TexLive update in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: texstudio, unicode, updating

I am new in Ubuntu and Tex so, from searching on here  and on the Ubuntu forum, I (think) I managed to install TexLive 2020. But the version used on TexStudio is still TexLive 2017. Can I do something to update the version (I checked the update option of the app, but it says it is updated) an if yes what is this? I want to update so that I maybe solve a problem I have with semicolon in greek not showing up right and have a more updated version. It shows up as an upper dot.

EDIT: The problem with the semicolon is solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140601/cant-make-greek-sign-of-question-shown-right/140607#140607).

I leave [this](https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/) as well.

Comment: Exactly how did you install TeXLive 2020?

Comment: @daleif Using the terminal and the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: As Raven mentions that does not install TL2020. It is not really available from Ubuntu for (18.04). It might be for 20.04 or 21.04

Comment: @daleif Well I can't upgrade to 20.04 or 21.04 because I need some other apps that don't have versions for them. Is there a tex editor for ubuntu that uses TL 2020? I have also tried texmaker but I am not very sutisfied.

Comment: Ubuntu has not provided tl20 for 18.04, it has nothing to do with the editor. If texlive was ever installed because of an editor it was because of recommends. Your only bet here is to install up steam tl21 as raven describes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you stated that you installed TeXLive (TL) via the Ubuntu repositories. However you are using Ubunto 18.04, which ships only TL2017 in its repositories (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/texlive). Therefore by executing `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` you are installing TL2017 and not TL2020.

If you want to install a more recent version of TL (independent of the Ubuntu repos), you will have to do it manually. But no worries this is not a big deal. The process is described at http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Essentially it boils down to:

1. Download the zip from http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
2. Extract the zip
3. Run the `install-tl` script (if I remeber correctly you'll want to run this script as sudo in order for it to be able to install TL into system directories)
4. Adapt the configuration of TL interactively via the script
5. Let the script install TL (this will take a while for it to download all files to your computer)

Note: You might want to uninstall the TL version from the Ubuntu repos before performing above steps. For that check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483/248968).

EDIT: If you only want to update TeXStudio and continue using the TL version you have already installed, you can install a more recent TeXStudio version via their PPA repo. The process is described here: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/02/texstudio-3-0-5-released-install-official-ubuntu-ppa/

Comment: I tried the second solution so that I don't get in too much trouble, but didn't work. Still TL2017. Maybe I should only try to solve the problem with the semicolon. However I tried to compile the tex file in overleaf where TL2020 is used and it didn't solve the problem. I guess something else is the problem and not the old TL version.

Comment: Explain how you added to the path? There is a very common mistake a lot of people do

Comment: I followed exactly these steps (home directory) ```sudo apt-get remove texstudio-doc texstudio-l10n

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sunderme/texstudio

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install texstudio```

Comment: Texstudio has nothing to do with texlive, this only gives you a newer texstudio not a newer texlive